# File structure for ExpressJs with Angular2 project

Tags: node.js, express, angular

How would a typical **ExpressJs** and **Angular2** file structure look like.
At the moment i have this:

```
 Project
 |
 |--bin
 |--node_modules
 |--public
     |--images
     |--javascripts
     |--stylesheets
 |--routes
 |--views
 |--app.js
 |--package.json
```

In my public folder I have *index.pug* and *layout.pug*. This is the default structure as provided by expressJs. now that i want to add Angular2 where will i put my angular files? can i use boostrap with jade?let me add that am new to node. thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems what you're looking for is something similar to a standard MEAN-stack application (though your database may not be MongoDB). You should use [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/) to automatically generate an Angular2 project within that project directory as shown:

```
Project
|-angular2-project-directory/
    |--src/
    |--package.json
    |--README.md
    |--...(Other Angular CLI generated files)
|--routes/
|--views/
|--app.js
|--package.json
```

Hope this helps!